# Python Jira API will not authenticate with API Token

Tags: python, api, jira

When I manually run a python script to connect to Jira I have no issues just passing my username and API token, however when I run via Cron I get an error stating

`response text = Basic authentication with passwords is deprecated.`

I have tried to encode the tuple of username and API token in base64, however this still doesn't seem to work. Has anyone gotten basic authentication to work to Jira Cloud via Cron?